# BabylonJS Radial vs Rectangular Textures (Conversion or Code Change)

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl, texture-mapping, babylonjs

I am working with the planetary textures from [this site](http://planetpixelemporium.com/earth.html). They are all in rectangular form.

[image]

However, in my BabylonJS application, textures are expected to be like this.

[image: What I want]

I have tried setting the coordinates mode, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
// These didn't have an effect
material.diffuseTexture.coordinatesMode = BABYLON.Texture.SPHERICAL_MODE;
material.diffuseTexture.coordinatesMode = BABYLON.Texture.EXPLICIT_MODE;
material.diffuseTexture.coordinatesMode = BABYLON.Texture.SPHERICAL_MODE;
material.diffuseTexture.coordinatesMode = BABYLON.Texture.PLANAR_MODE;
material.diffuseTexture.coordinatesMode = BABYLON.Texture.CUBIC_MODE;
material.diffuseTexture.coordinatesMode = BABYLON.Texture.PROJECTION_MODE;
material.diffuseTexture.coordinatesMode = BABYLON.Texture.SKYBOX_MODE;
```

Is there a way to convert between these two kinds of textures? Alternatively, are their planet textures like the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact this is related to the texture coordinates embedded into your mesh. You should use Blender to export different coordinates or you can also play with texture.uOffset, texture.vOffset, texture.uScale and texture.vScale to move your texture on your mesh